# Eclipse Marketplace hangs (Luna, Java8)

Tags: eclipse, java-8, eclipse-luna, eclipse-marketplace

My newly installed Eclipse Luna hangs when I launch Marketplace. I tried to move my workspace out of the way, clean everything, re-install and start fresh.

It would still hang and has to be killed -9.  I saved the stack trace (as well as versions of the OS, Java, and Eclipse) at https://gist.github.com/c51821cbd4e676cd7c9f

The funny part is, things go just fine if I switch back Java1.7.0_25.  I'd like to use Java8 though.

Is that a known problem and are there ways around it?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to un-install and install again the Java8 JDK. Have you tried that?
Have you got multiple JDK installed? If yes try with just Java8 (un-install the others).

Or try also to run eclipse with

```
eclipse -vm c:\java8path\jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

or

```
eclipse -vm c:\java8path\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
```